# I can't save an Gif from a URL with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, gif, animated-gif

I get a link from Tenor and I want to get the gif downloaded. I use this code (Python 3.6):

```
from urllib import request
request.urlretrieve('https://media.tenor.com/images/0ba0cfa366db09213ab0352834b53bdf/tenor.gif', 'myfile.gif')
```

But I get this error form the console:

```
request.urlretrieve('https://media.tenor.com/images/0ba0cfa366db09213ab0352834b53bdf/tenor.gif', 'C:\Users\Javier Jiménez\Documents\Javi\BOT\myfile.gif')
                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I hope you could help me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set utf-8 encoding before this code ? it's working fine for me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I found another way like this:    from urllib import request
 imagen = requests.get(gif).content

 with open('gif_BOT.gif', 'wb') as handler:
  handler.write(imagen)                     And it works